# Joomla - how to add abutton upload file to parameter of template and do upload file?

Tags: joomla

i custom a parameter to add a button upload `<input type="file" name="file">`

But how to upload when we are in com_template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to tweak to make the upload work.

1. Change form's enctype to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
2. If using MVC architecture, add `task` and `controller` to the form.

Uploading of file is pretty easy, because Joomla has `filesystem` package in place. All you need to upload the file is to call `JFile::upload($src, $dest)`.

Read about filesystem package, you will find a lot of useful stuff. Here is the link http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package

Here is what uploading code looks like (from Joomla documentation)

```
/**
 * Uploading function for Joomla
 * @param int $max maximum allowed site of file
 * @param string $module_dir path to where to upload file
 * @param string $file_type allowed file type
 * @return string response message
 */    
function fileUpload($max, $module_dir, $file_type){
        //Retrieve file details from uploaded file, sent from upload form
        $file = JRequest::getVar('file_upload', null, 'files', 'array'); 
        // Retorna: Array ( [name] => mod_simpleupload_1.2.1.zip [type] => application/zip 
        // [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpo3VG9F [error] => 0 [size] => 4463 ) 

        if(isset($file)){ 
                //Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
                $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

                if($file['size'] > $max) $msg = JText::_('ONLY_FILES_UNDER').' '.$max;
                //Set up the source and destination of the file

                $src = $file['tmp_name'];
                $dest = $module_dir . DS . $filename;

                //First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
                if ($file['type'] == $file_type || $file_type == '*') { 
                   if ( JFile::upload($src, $dest) ) {

                       //Redirect to a page of your choice
                        $msg = JText::_('FILE_SAVE_AS').' '.$dest;
                   } else {
                          //Redirect and throw an error message
                        $msg = JText::_('ERROR_IN_UPLOAD');
                   }
                } else {
                   //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
                        $msg = JText::_('FILE_TYPE_INVALID');
                }

        }
        return $msg;
}
```

Comment: it should go into the controller. You have to register the controller event for your form's submit action or change it to protected/private method and  call within the controller

Comment: How do I call the function? Every time I put it in controller then try to call it gives me an error, eg. class                  MJobsControllerMJob extends JControllerForm
{
 private function test1(){
  
  echo "<span style=\"color: red;\">THIS IS INSIDE THE CONTROLLER TEST</span>";
 }
 test1();
}
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION