# how to upload image in joomla admin componenet?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, file-upload, components, joomla1.5

i have not found a suitable answer can anyone plese tell me the way to upload images and send mail through a mvc component in joomla what are the changes required in model view controller of the component

i have done building component for the admin backend using the following example

http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components/component-dev-partii

how can i implement image file upload through browse in the following example can anyone help me .

Comment: actually i would prefer to upload image by coding rather than any plugin has it would be more benifiical in learning joomla component

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690303/joomla-how-to-add-abutton-upload-file-to-parameter-of-template-and-do-upload-fi/3691663#3691663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$src = $file ['tmp_name'];   // source temp location

$dest = JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . "logo" . DS . $newfilename; // destination

JFile::upload ( $src, $dest );  // file upload function in joomla

$result = $model->updatePic ( $filename );   // update function has you require to update the filename in database .